# java : When memory returns in method?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, methods, return

I know that the memory returns after the function ends.

When does thread object is returned? -
when does the variable A is returned?

```
public  AAA () {

     int a = 1;
     new thread() {
             public void run() {

             }
    }.start();
}
```

---

sorry.

When is A removed from the stack?  after AAA() ends or thread ends?

When is the thread object removed from the heap?

Comment: What do you mean by "returned"?

Comment: First, it wouldn't compile, since it's `Thread`, and not `thread`.  Second, it's not "returning" anything, since the return of `run` is `void`.  Third, it would spin up the thread and join back (relatively) fast, as there's no work to be done in the main body of the thread.

Comment: Google "automatic storage" and "call/return stack".  For extra credit you can Google "garbage collection", in particular with regard to Java.

Answer (score 2):

I think "returned" was a poor choice of wording in your question, and that what you're asking is "when is X removed from the heap?" - i.e. "when can the memory I allocated to X be reallocated to something else?"

If that's the case, you're asking about something called [Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html), which is an ongoing process by which Java finds things you can't use anymore - "garbage" - and removes them from memory.

Simply put, **something becomes "garbage" when it becomes unreachable** - when there are no remaining references to it.

To use an example I think you're alluding to:

```
void foo() {
  int a = 1;
  //do stuff 
  return; 
}
```

Each time `foo()` executes, memory space is allocated for a new local variable `a`. Each time it finishes executing, there's no way you can ever refer to that variable again, therefore it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Once the threads run method is exited the reference to the thread object in the stack is freed and the thread object can be garbage collected.